# Force PHP to keep array indexes in the order they were defined?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to be clever and return all the information I need to sort and display friends of the app user and the user-defined groups they belong to. It's important to keep them in group order first then friend order after. So far, I have this query that works perfectly:

```
SELECT * FROM friends 
            left join `groups` 
            on `groups`.id = friends.group_id 
            where `friends`.user_id = 1 
            ORDER BY `groups`.priority ASC, friends.priority ASC
```

It returns information exactly as I expected with nulls for group information where the friends aren't in a group. For that I have a catchall (reserved group name) "friends" group and sort it into a few arrays for later user like so:

```
        foreach ($rows as $group_friend) {
            // group id or keyword "friends" if null
            $group_id = ($group_friend['group_id']?:'friends');
            // Do it this way to prevent duplicates AND make it accessible by either index or value
            $user['groups'][$group_id] = $group_id;
            $user['friends'][] = $group_friend['friend_id'];
            $user['group_friends'][$group_id][] = $group_friend['friend_id'];
        }
```

The query is run on a backend php page accessed through a CURL request from the front in JSON format. When I load the backend.php?get_user=1 page, I see the user data, but the group stuff is out of order:

```
groups  
    23  "23"
    24  "24"
    25  "25"
    friends "friends"
friends 
    0   "8"
    1   "9"
    2   "16"
    3   "2"
    4   "12"
    5   "20"
    6   "97"
    7   "98"
    8   "3"
    9   "4"
    10  "99"
    11  "100"
    12  "129"
    13  "17"
    14  "18"
    15  "165"
group_friends   
    23  
        0   "3"
        1   "4"
        2   "99"
        3   "100"
        4   "129"
    24  
        0   "2"
        1   "12"
        2   "20"
        3   "97"
        4   "98"
    25  
        0   "17"
        1   "18"
        2   "165"
    friends 
        0   "8"
        1   "9"
        2   "16"
```

The order is largely maintained, but group 24 has higher priority than 23 and should be first. When I output the results of the query, it properly shows all 24 group data before 23, but it ends up flipped in the resulting arrays (both of them). Other than writing it to have a numerical index instead to force the order, what can I do?

I considered setting the index for groups to be the priority, but priority is an optional field and can have duplicates (null).

Comment: The hack: prefix the group id with `group-` so that PHP doesn't assume its a numeric array index; the solution: keep a separate array with the correct sequence and iterate over that to get groups in the correct order.

Comment: This is something to do with the way you are displaying the data (or perhaps processing it further); PHP will retain ordering according to the way you entered values into the array, so if `24` was put in first as a key, it will come out first too. See for example: https://3v4l.org/2PBCJ

Comment: 24 is definitely in first due to the resuts of the query coming back in order. I validated it by dumping the sql results directly. Despite that the resulting arrays are out of order when I dump it as JSON

Comment: For now, it does seem that using text keys is working. Doesn't seem it should be necessary, but apparently there are some shenanigans at work.